# How to add values from the GAE dashboard to a missing field

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I added a new field, "phone", to my "restaurant" object. I modified the form where restaurants are posted, and it works just fine. I can see for my latest restaurants their phone numbers in the GAE dashboard, when I go to Datastore viewer. However, the old restaurants, have as value for the new "phone" column, the value <\missing>

My question is how can I add values for this column, from the dashoard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the "Datastore viewer" then select the kind of entity you want to modify.

Select the individual item by clicking on it's ID/Name, add the data then click save.

Now, it's probably the case you've tried this and it won't work because those "old" models literally don't have the field present so you can update it. Changing a model does not update all the older saved instances of that model, as you've noticed.

So you'll have to write a bit of code that loads them, presents them to you in some kind of interface then you can add the relevant value then re-save it, then in the datastore it'll have the field you want and it can be updated from the admin interface in the future. But until that field exists on that model you can't add content to the field.

Or you could write a bit of code that loads the entities, then saves them again straight away and you could then edit them in the datastore (as saving them would add the field). Depends on the volume really what the easiest way to go is.

Comment: Yeah, i've done something similar to what you said. Basically i went through all my entities, and set them a dummy value for that filed (I done this by creating a litle bit of code, that gets executed for example when I enter a link). After I had the dummy values, i edited those in the dashboard as I liked. This works well for a small number of entities